# Click to scroll to content within div JQuery not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tabbed section which has content in div scrolling based on link clicked position but scrolling is not working properly, here is the [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/g62xr37g/)

and this is the code firing on click

```
$(document).ready(function ($){
    $('.scrollable_tab > ul > li > a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.scrollable_content_main').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take an account of the container div as well.
Try like this.

```
$('.scrollable_tab > ul > li > a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
        console.log($(".scrollable_content_main").scrollTop()+target.offset().top );
        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.scrollable_content_main').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".scrollable_content_main").scrollTop() + target.offset().top 
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xcht52eh/